# SO question with many answers and comments is lagging

Tags: bug

My browser (*google chrome 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)*) has a hard time in scrolling through that page (**I don't use the *scroll button* on my mouse - I'm using drag&drop (click with the left mouse button on that scrollbar and then try to drag down the scrollbar button)**). This question has already 2 pages and it is lagging (scrollbar on the right side) when I try to scroll down.

It would probably be better to put less content on a single page and split it over multiple pages with less answers.

**Example:**

[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons?rq=1)

[image]

---

Same problem described here

- [Scrolling performance in Chrome in large posts suddenly got worse over the past week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389222/scrolling-performance-in-chrome-in-large-posts-suddenly-got-worse-over-the-past)
- [Scrolling on Stack Overflow is slow if a question has lots of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333166/scrolling-on-stack-overflow-is-slow-if-a-question-has-lots-of-answers)

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro. But then I have 16GB of RAM and a Core i7-7700K CPU and a GTX 980 Ti video card. Not top of the line by any means.

Comment: Cross site duplicate on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333166/scrolling-on-stack-overflow-is-slow-if-a-question-has-lots-of-answers

Comment: "Not top of the line by any means.", @HereticMonkey your PC is too overpowered for simple internet usage (like SO). Imho even pentium 4 would be ok to surf through the internet. I don't think that hardware is an issue here.

Comment: @notyourdolly Can you try a different browser? I see no lagginess in Firefox 69.0 (logged in to SO) or in Edge (not logged in) on Windows 10. Do you happen to be using graphics on the CPU rather than a discrete graphics card?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Everything is fine on Firefox: *Firefox Quantum 69.0 (64-Bit)*. "Do you happen to be using graphics on the CPU rather than a discrete graphics card?" - **no**.

Comment: @notyourdolly So might you be reporting a problem with Chrome rather than Stack Overflow? Could you have disabled hardware acceleration in Chrome at some point?

Comment: @AndrewMorton nope. here: https://samsclass.info/old-classes.html and here: https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2011/12/31/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-11-heap-spraying-demystified/ i don't have any problems, no lags. Only here on SO.

Comment: @Black Thunder: GIFs aren't known for high frame rates that would enable you to appreciate the extent of this issue...

Comment: I made a video but I think it doesn't help in making things clear. Another topic explains it already really well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333166/

Comment: @BoltClock It's dependent on the tool used or the skills required to make a GIF. I have made dozens of 25+ fps good quality GIFs.

Comment: It could be hardware in addition to other things. For instance, I use Privacy Badger, which blocks Google Analytics, Quantserve, and other analytics scripts SO adds.

Comment: @HereticMonkey maybe it has something to do with adblocker? i doubt that it could be an issue here specifically on that site.

Comment: @Black Thunder: 25 isn't a good baseline for this sort of thing. You want 60 minimum. I'm sure there are GIFs out there with this frame rate but they're not common, and probably a pain to export at that frame rate.

Comment: @BoltClock 25 is enough for this thing.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue - the slowness is caused by a Forced Reflow in Chrome. I put details in this posting: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389222/scrolling-performance-in-chrome-in-large-posts-suddenly-got-worse-over-the-past?noredirect=1#comment726521_389222 - this is **definitely** a bug because the reflow events don't happen in smaller QA posts - and this only started happening within the past week - independent of any Chrome updates.

Comment: It seems to be caused by the popovers UI elements, hiding them through `.s-popover { display: none }` CSS rule makes things a lot smoother on my chrome.

Comment: Duping to the newer question as it contains more information..