# Scrolling performance in Chrome in large posts suddenly got worse over the past week

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-experience, performance

Ever since sometime in the past week, I noticed that dragging the Chrome vertical scrollbar in "large" posts was very jerky and not silky smooth.

I'm running Chrome 76 64-bit on Windows 10 x64, running at 96 dpi.

This issue only affects "large" Stack Overflow posts - smaller posts have smooth scrolling with no abnormalities.

#### Repro steps

1. Open Chrome on Windows
2. Be logged-in to stackoverflow.com
3. Visit [C# (.NET) Design Flaws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411906/c-sharp-net-design-flaws/413093#413093)
4. Resize the browser window to something like 1400x1200
5. Drag the vertical scrollbar.
6. Observe the scrolling is choppy/slow/janky

#### Investigation

I fired up Chrome's Developer Tools and did a performance profiler run as I dragged the scrollbar up and down for a few seconds:

[image]

Observe the red lines at the top (the [red indicates layout events, which are bad - and should not happen during scrolling](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/)). Zooming in we can see that Chrome is complaining about a Forced Reflow:

[image]

Looking at the anonymous-function in the inverted flame-graph...

[image]

...shows that some code is running a JavaScript animation (using `requestAnimationFrame`) which causes a DOM reflow - though I don't know why it happens during scrolling:

[image]

For comparison, I opened a shorter/smaller Q&A posting (*[Use group by and having count in update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850258/use-group-by-and-having-count-in-update-statement)*) and did the same test, and the profiler reported the same animation code was running - but no DOM reflow was being triggered (observe the lack of red markers):

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SO question with many answers and comments is lagging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389212/so-question-with-many-answers-and-comments-is-lagging)

Comment: @Mat Ah, I didn't see that posting. My posting is a duplicate - but my post has more details - sooooo - I'd like to keep my effortpost alive please :D

Comment: really well explained. thank you for your effort.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333166/scrolling-on-stack-overflow-is-slow-if-a-question-has-lots-of-answers

Answer (score 10):

This is fixed as of late last week - thanks for the report!

### Background

Click "share" below one of the answers on that page. You'll see the little pop-up that lets you copy the URL.

Now scroll the page until the pop-up would start to go out of view... It flips around to stay visible as long as the share link itself is in view!

Nifty, eh? And that's why it triggers some updates on scroll...

...but it really didn't need to be doing that for every hidden pop-up on every post on the page. Or, any hidden pop-ups. That just made things slow.

So Aaron and the Stacks team altered the logic here to only handle these events for *visible* pop-ups. And scrolling should once again be smooth.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem anymore: the original question I linked to now scrolls smoothly - perhaps they fixed it already?

Comment: Should've emphasized the last paragraph a bit more... Edited!